# Do I need to clean/remove the images created on deployments of my Cloud Run instance?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a Cloud Run instance up and running on my Google Cloud Platform project.

Whenever I do any changes to my `main.py` file, I perform the following steps:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag ${CONTAINER}
gcloud run deploy ${SERVICE} --image $CONTAINER --platform managed
```

which builds a new image and deploys the container to a managed instance.

Is a good practice to find and remove the images of older deployments, or is this managed automatically by GCP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Container images are not automatically removed by Google. You have to delete them manually if you want.

There is no good practice, as it depends. If you are sure that you will not use old images anymore, you can delete them; otherwise, you may want to keep them to rollback easily to an older version. If you are using Container Registry, note that it costs money to store images (https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/pricing#storage).

If you manage your code with version control systems like Git, you can simply rebuild and redeploy an older version by doing `git checkout <your-commit-id>` and run commands in your question. So in that particular case, I think this is not very useful to keep all your images since you can always regenerate them easily.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am deploying an application on development phase, so I definitely want to remove the older images. When using the `gcloud builds` command, shall I find the bucket where the images are being stored and remove them manually, or is there something like a dashboard where I can see all the images associated with a service and remove them from there?

Comment: I suppose that you are deploying your image to Container Registry, so from the console (https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/<your-project-id>), you can find/delete images. You can also use CLI to delete images (`gcloud container images delete`).

Answer (score 0):

If your CICD pipeline is consistently building and pushing images then yes, you should at least remove the ones not used for production like untagged images (duplicate `latest`, etc.) as you are charged for storage on both artifact and container registry.

There is an unofficial [GCR-cleaner](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcr-cleaner) image that you can use to automatically clean images. You can deploy it through a scheduled github actions workflow, cloud run + cloud scheduler. You can even run it as a one-off task or deploy it using the terraform module.